# Ban Criteria - What are the exact business rules?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I have a reputation of more than 10K on some forums but banned from SuperUser! Where can I see the reason for the ban?

There are some initial information on that but it did not help.

I can see that someone down-voted one of my questions. Is this so bad?

Is this by design or is it a bug? If it is by design could some one list the business rules clearly?

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reputation does not translate between sites. It is up to you to show that you can ask high-quality on-topic questions on each site.

You have asked a total of 17 questions on this site

- 9 of them have been deleted
- 5 were closed or migrated
- only 2 questions have positive votes
- 4 questions have a score of -1 or less

As such have received an automated ban. This is entirely enforced by the system and when you attempted to post a question you should have received a link to the page regarding question bans. If not then go to [this page](https://superuser.com/help/question-bans) and carefully read everything there.  Specifically

> At Stack Exchange, asking questions is a privilege, not a right. If a user cannot demonstrate, after asking a reasonable number of questions, that their contributions are making the site better (or at very least, not making it worse) then they will be blocked from asking further questions until they have demonstrated their ability to contribute positively.

and

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

Your questions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the business rules. I am surprised with the deleted questions. I never ask stupid questions.Maybe I miss understood the forum's purpose.

Comment: @NoChance - We are not a forum.  Calling Stack Exchange a forum is an indicator you don’t understand the purpose.  Deleted questions still exist,  theoretically they could be undeleted, if they were improved and received enough undelete votes.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information.

Answer (score 4):

#### Could some one list the business rules clearly?

Bans (question or answer) are automated and nobody knows the exact rules (which are kept secret to prevent users from playing the system).

> I can see that someone down-voted one of my questions. Is this so bad?

By itself, no, that is not so bad. However, you have asked 17 questions (of which 9 have been deleted).

You have had 2 upvotes and 7 downvotes (votes on deleted questions count towards your average) which gives you an aggregate score of -5 and a question ban for asking poor quality questions.

> Can someone please help?

Only you can help be following the instructions you were given when you were informed of the ban.

See [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account? - Help Center - Super User](https://superuser.com/help/question-bans)